# Java Script - Convert Object to XML and XML to Object while using custom names of attributes

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I need to convert XML to Object and Object to XML in java script. (I can use a Json conversion in the middle of the conversion process)

But, I want to use my custom tag name and custom attribute name while converting, for example:

Person Object:

```
function PersonObject(firstName, lastName) {
   this.FirstName = firstName;
   this.LastName = lastName
}
```

Convert to XML like this:

```
<person f_name="First Name" l_name="Last Name" />
```

Something like saving metadata for every property in the object (in C# I did it with writing attribute: `[XmlAttribute("f_name")]` above the property).

I want to do it dynamically and not to give the objects properties those names because I want the continuing code to be readable.

So, How can I do it - Convert easily object to XML and vice versa while using custom names of attributes?

Comment: do you want to generate xmls on the client side? why not do this on the server(if you have one).

Comment: I need to do it in the client side and to send it to the server